# Php JSON Response Array

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I have this php code. As you can see i query a mysql database through a function showallevents. I return a the $result to the $event variable. With the while loop i assign the values that i get from event to a response array and every time the loop happens the rows are stored in the data array. Surely i am failing somewhere because despite i am getting a correct number of responses all the values that i get at json are "null". Also it tells me something about JSONarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

```
 if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') 
 {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// include db handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'showallevents') 
{
    // Request type is show all events
    // show all events
    $event = $db->showallevents();
    if ($event != false)
    {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($event)) 
        {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["uid"] = $event["uid"];
        $response["event"]["date"] = $event["date"];
        $response["event"]["hours"] = $event["hours"];
        $response["event"]["store_name"] = $event["store_name"];
        $response["event"]["event_information"] = $event["event_information"];
        $response["event"]["event_type"] = $event["event_type"];
        $response["event"]["Phone"] = $event["Phone"];
        $response["event"]["address"] = $event["address"];
        $response["event"]["created_at"] = $event["created_at"];
        $response["event"]["updated_at"] = $event["updated_at"];
        $data[]=$response;

        }
        echo json_encode($data);            
    }
    else 
    {
        // event not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Events not found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
  else 
 { 
echo "Access Denied"; 
 }
}
?>
```

the DB_Functions.php

```
     <?php

    class DB_Functions 
   {

private $db;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() 
{
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct()
{

}


/**
 * Select all events that are after yesterday.
 */
public function showallevents()
{
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date >= CURDATE()");
   return($result);
   }

   }

  ?>
```

ok the code that helped me put all data into an array was this

```
            $data = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($event)) 
        {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["event"]= $row;
        $data[]=$response;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've merged two independent pieces of code and wound up with a mess whose result is unclear.

You can create an associative array in two ways:

```
$array = (key=>value, key2=>value2);
```

You can also use:

```
$array[key]=value;
$array[key2]=value2;
```

Note that both 'key' and 'value' are simply variables; you can use strings there, or pass in a variable from someplace else.

When doing similar things, I use the following approach:

```
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["uid"] = $event["uid"];
    $response["event"]["date"] = $event["date"];
    $response["event"]["hours"] = $event["hours"];
    $response["event"]["store_name"] = $event["store_name"];
    $response["event"]["event_information"] = $event["event_information"];
    $response["event"]["event_type"] = $event["event_type"];
    $response["event"]["Phone"] = $event["Phone"];
    $response["event"]["address"] = $event["address"];
    $response["event"]["created_at"] = $event["created_at"];
    $response["event"]["updated_at"] = $event["updated_at"];
    $data[]=$response;
```

Comment: Well after using this method i managed to get at logcat 3 responses which is supposed to be the number of rows i should get according to the mysql query that i perform.. The problem is that it return null values. It says that jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject.

Comment: At a guess, check the result of your showallevents() function.  It's probably not returning what you think it is.

Comment: This is not the case since the rows that i expect to get back are correct. I am posting the Db_functions.php after the main code with the showallevents in order to make things easier.

Comment: Then I'm not entirely sure what's going on.  What, exactly, is saying that jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject?

Comment: i am posting 1 pic with the json response i get with null results and  1 pic with the error message. thx for your time by the way whatever the result.

Comment: Hrm...  it's looking like $event['foo'] is returning null.  If so, it's probably (again) how you're retrieving the data.  Try an 'echo $event['date']' and see what you get out of it.  Try that for several of the different data types and see what happens.

Comment: ok what i did  in order to get correct response was while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($event)){
  $data[] = $row; }     this worked to me and i got back results... the only problem is that i still get the error message of jsonarray cannot be converted to json object.. if you have any info about that i would appreciate it.. :)

Comment: Actually, looking at what you've posted, I'm not sure what you're doing anymore.  It looks like you've actually moved from one issue (getting the data into the array) which you've solved, to a new issue (the JSON conversion).  And even then, the data you've posted shows that you've already converted your data to JSON, so what are you trying to do?  (In other words: accept an answer to this question, and think about asking a new one)

Comment: the goal from the beginning was to parse the data from sql to the application through json.. i managed to put all data in json format but i cant parse them because of the error that i described . i will accept an answer in a few mins and post the code that i have.. thx for helping and sorry for not answering due to work load

Comment: It's cool.  I guess I didn't quite understand the question.  These things happen.  So the error occurs when DECODING the JSON?  I don't know enough about android to help with the decode stage, alas.

Comment: its all good i just had to parse jarray instead of jobj :) have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your `$response` variable?
In PHP to create associative arrays, you use `=>` and not `=`

for example:

```
$array = ('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to return all the arrays, can you use mysql_fetch_assoc in stead of mysql_fetch_row?

```
    if ($tag == 'showallevents') 
{
    // Request type is show all events
    // show all events
    $event = $db->showallevents();
    if ($event != false)
    {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($event)) 
        {
        $data[] = $row;
        echo json_encode($data);            
    }
    else 
    {
        // event not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Events not found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}

     else
    {
echo "Access Denied";
   }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: when i used mysql_fetch_array command it returned only 1 row at the $result. so i had some response but it was only 1 row of the data.